# How to add some value in generic wildcard map<?,?>

Tags: java, generics, generic-collections, unbounded-wildcard

I have gone through couple of related questions but those are not help me out. Actually, I have a method whose return type is `Map<?,?>` and I want to do unit test using Mockito. Sample Code is:

```
Map<?, ?> resultMap = dataServiceMapper.getData(serviceContext, requestData.getId());
```

and I want to Mock this:

```
dataServiceMapper.getData(serviceContext, requestData.getId()):
```

Mocking Code is :

```
Mockito.when(mapperMock.getData(any(ServiceContext.class), anyString())).thenReturn(value).
```

In value if I return normal Map with String then its throwing compile time error except null (as per documentation).

But I want to add some data like String so that after getting mocking map data I can do further work.

Comment: Can you add the signature of the method you are trying to mock?

Comment: *"Actually, I have a method whose return type is Map<?,?>"* ... rethink your API design?  Writing a method that forces the clients of your API to deal with wildcard types is suboptimal.

Comment: @Darshan Mehta : public Map<?,?> getData(@Param(EntityConstants.CONTEXT)ServiceContext serviceContext,@Param("reportId") String reportId). Here ServiceContext is normal POJO class where getter and setter methods are there.

Comment: @scottb : Thanks for reply but that API is not designed by me, but I have to mock that method and set some data but I couldn't. Is there is having some possibility to put some data inside the map then please share some sample code.

Comment: What a huge abuse of generics. Not only getting `Map<?,?>` as a result is useless, but then you try to add data in the map?

Comment: @Kayaman : that is the requirement. So if possible then please share some sample code. and my main concern is to do mock the method and return map thats why I want to add some value (except null because null only accepting).

Comment: Why not ask the person who designed the API to change it so it's properly testable? It's clearly broken after all.

Comment: *"So if possible then please share some sample code..."* ... it is impossible to compile code that adds any value to a `Map<?,?>` other than `null`.  And it is a good thing too, because allowing it would violate the fundamental type safety guarantees made by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

To mock a method, all you need to do is pass a `Map` without generic type. Generics are removed after compilation anyway, and all you are doing is writing a test so, implementation similar to below example should work:

```
//Actual method
public Map<?, ?> getData(String input){
    return null;
}

//Test
public void test() {
    Test2 t2 = Mockito.mock(Test2.class);
    Map result = new HashMap();
    Mockito.when(t2.getData(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(result);
}
```

Comment: null is fine but apart from null I want to add some String data because in later cases I want to get data from map like resultMap.get("ID").toString()

Comment: I found one solution.                                                   
Map map = new HashMap();                        
map.put("TEST","TEST_DATA"); Mockito.when(t2.getData(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(map);  here its accepting the HashMap object.